# How can I connect metal rods together crosswise?

Tags: materials, storage, support

I have some stainless steel rods of diameters such a 1/4", 3/8", 1/2" or so, and I want to connect them together in some cases cross-wise to make a lattice. In some cases it might be convenient to connect them at an angle like 45-degrees. How can I do this? The rods will need to be taken apart sometimes, so it cannot be a permanent bond. Also, I don't want to use anything that will leave adhesive on the rods or gum them up.

One obvious idea is to use baling wire and just wrap it around the joint, but it might slip.

Comment: Welding? Clamps of some sort?  Weave or twist them together as is done in fences? I think we need to know more about what you're trying to build before we can recommend specific solutions.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research I found these that cost $12 each, pretty expensive, but am open to better suggestions:

[image: lattice connector]

Comment: These tightening screws can damage/scratch pipe surface a little. For no possibility of that kind of 'intrusion', You can easily find similar joints modelled as clamps. As I recall, some sort of shop furniture is assembled that way.

Answer (score 1):

For light duty, easily removable attachment, stainless steel safety wire is available, buy a spool of 0.41 and a pair of safety wire twisters. Put a couple wraps around the rods and twist the free ends up to tighten. Better than bailing wire, won't rust. Use a pair of dikes to snip it loose when you need to remove it.

Safety wire is used on industrial/heavy equipment or aircraft. It fits through drilled heads on bolts or through castle nuts and drilled holes on the thread end. With that information, it should be easily found with an internet search.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [cable clamps](http://www.blairwirerope.com/artwork/cableclamps/clamp2.jpg)? Getting large enough ones to straddle the crossed wires will hold them together, be removable and you can set them so it controls the grid you create, whether it be set square or diagonal.

The "legs" of the bottom part of the clamp can be cut off, or there are "U" bolts that have a flat plate to hold parts together.